# Does AMP Support Google Tag Manager (GTM)?

Tags: amp-html

I have browsed around the web and there are some older threads that say that it's not supported yet.

Any idea about the current state?

Thanks!
I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have also checked the documentations and I think Google Tag Manager is still not supported. It is stated in this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/2hp84ziiZKQ) that in many ways it doesn't seem a good fit.

> One key of AMP, is performance, and allowing the runtime to optimize loading. Tag Manager adds a level of indirection, and complication. 
>   Adding the tag manager to a page, adds an arbitrary number of further dependencies.

You can use other existing tags like [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/) tag, instead.

I also found this [related StackExchange question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91549/google-tag-manager-and-amp) and he  tried adding the GTM using [Glue for Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/glue-for-yoast-seo-amp/) and it did track the pages but unfortunately resulted in 2 AMP validation errors.

> The proper way of implementing the tag as of right now is via amp-pixel or amp-analytics. I used amp-analytics tag myself. First you would add this in the head:
>
> ```
> <script async custom-element="amp-analytics"
>     src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
> ```
>
> And then the tracking code goes in the body inside this tag using
>   JSON:
>
> ```
>  <amp-analytics type="googleanalytics" id="analytics1"></amp-analytics>
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The current state is represented by this issue: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/3380